# Как парсить строку в оператор сравнения?

Tags: javascript

Я реализовал метод для фильтрации товаров по указанным опциям. Метод принимает в качестве параметра объект options, который содержит параметры для поиска, например: {name: "item 2", price: "<= 1000", count: "> 2"}, каждый из параметров является опциональными. Метод должен возвращать отфильтрованный массив с товарами. filterProductBy (options). 
Мне удалось фильтровать по имени. Скажите, как правильно фильтровать по числу

**обязательное условие передачи в таком виде:**

```
console.log(shop.filterProductsBy({ 
name: "product", 
count: ">=10", 
price: ">=200" }));
```

«count» и «price» необходимо парсить вместе с оператором сравнения, который устанавливает диапазон фильтра, вот объект, который, я думаю может это сделать, как мне реализовать его в моем методе, чтобы все работало?

```
        let operators = {
        '===': function (a, b) { return a === b; },
        '==': function (a, b) { return a == b; },
        '<=': function (a, b) { return a <= b; },
        '>=': function (a, b) { return a >= b; },
        '<': function (a, b) { return a < b; },
        '>': function (a, b) { return a > b; }
    };
```

**Весь код:**

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
//Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor(products) {
        this.products = [];
    }
    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }
    //method for filtering products by specified parameters
    filterProductBy(options) {
        const optionName = options.name,
            optionCount = options.count,
            optionPrice = options.price;

        const filters = {
            byName: function (actualName, optionName) {
                return (actualName === undefined) || (actualName === optionName);
            },

            byCount: function (actualCount, optionCount) {
                return (actualCount === undefined) || (actualCount === optionCount);
            },

            byPrice: function (actualPrice, optionPrice) {
                return (actualPrice === undefined) || (actualPrice === optionPrice);
            }
    };
        return this.products.filter(
            (product) => filters.byName(product.name, optionName)
            || filters.byCount(product.count, optionCount)
            || filters.byPrice(product.price, optionPrice));
        }
}
const shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("item 2", 2, 100));
shop.addProduct(new Product("some 3", 3, 500));
shop.addProduct(new Product("anything 4", 4, 1000));
console.log(shop.filterProductBy({
    name: "product 1",
    count: ">1",
    price: ">=500"

}));
```

Comment: Так в ответе внизу ничего не отфильтровывается же. Или так и должно быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользоваться `eval` функцией.

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
//Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor(products) {
        this.products = [];
    }
    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }
    //method for filtering products by specified parameters
    filterProductBy(options) {
        const optionName = options.name,
            optionCount = options.count,
            optionPrice = options.price;

        const filters = {
            byName: function (actualName, optionName) {
                return (actualName === undefined) || (actualName === optionName);
            },

            byCount: function (actualCount, optionCount) {

                return (actualCount === undefined) || (eval(actualCount + optionCount));
            },

            byPrice: function (actualPrice, optionPrice) {
                return (actualPrice === undefined) || (eval(actualPrice + optionPrice));
            }
    };
        return this.products.filter(
            (product) => filters.byName(product.name, optionName)
            || filters.byCount(product.count, optionCount)
            || filters.byPrice(product.price, optionPrice));
        }
}
const shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("item 2", 2, 100));
shop.addProduct(new Product("some 3", 3, 500));
shop.addProduct(new Product("anything 4", 4, 1000));
console.log(shop.filterProductBy({
    name: "product 1",
    count: ">1",
    price: ">=500"

}));
```

[Метод eval() док](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)